# How to access the first file of a Finder::files() result?

Tags: php, symfony

How can I get the first file with [symfony/finder component](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/finder.html)?

I tried to do like this:

```
<?php
// ...
$finder = new Finder();
$finder
    ->files()
    ->in($this->getKernel()->getRootDir().'/../web/uploads/')
    ->name($filename);

    if (!$finder->count()) {
        throw new NotFoundHttpException('Image not found');
    }

    dump(
        $finder->count(), 
        $finder->getIterator()->current(), 
        $finder->getIterator()->valid()
    );
```

and I get this result:

```
1
null
false
```

Comment: This question applies if one wants to avoid using a foreach loop and break statement when one is only interested in the first result.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to `rewind` first or `\var_dump(\iterator_to_array($finder));`.

The sequence of an iterator is:

- rewind
- valid
- current/key
- next
- valid
- current/key
- next
- ...

Answer (score 13):

```
$iterator = $finder->getIterator();
$iterator->rewind();
$firstFile = $iterator->current();
```

Answer (score 3):

One-liner solution.

```
foreach ($finder as $file) {break;}

print "{$file->getPathname()} is the first file.\n";
```